# Pipe chain should start with a raw value

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have the following action in my Phoenix app controller:

```
  def index(conn, params) do
    studios =
      if params["search"] do
        Studio.search(Studio, params["search"])
      else
        Studio
      end
      |> Repo.all
      |> Repo.preload(:address)

    render conn, studios: studios
  end
```

When my run `mix credo` it returns following warning:

```
┃ [F] → Pipe chain should start with a raw value.
┃       lib/tattoo_backend/web/controllers/api/v1/studio_controller.ex:21 #(TattooBackend.Web.API.V1.StudioController.index)
```

I've tried to refactor that but I didn't find solution that will makes credo happy. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: how about: `params |> to_query() |> Repo.all() |> ...`, and having two definitions of `def to_query({"search" => search}), do: ...` and `def to_query(_params), do: Studio`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
queryable = 
  if params["search"] do
    Studio.search(Studio, params["search"])
  else
    Studio
  end

queryable
|> Repo.all()
|> Repo.preload(:address)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using pattern matching:

```
def index(conn, params) do
  params
  |> search
  |> Repo.all()
  |> Repo.preload(:address)
end

defp search(%{"search" => search}) do
  Studio.search(Studio, search)
end
defp search(_), do: Studio
```

Comment: I will go with this one, with minor improvement: change the `params["search"]` to just `search`, as you already got it by pattern matching. otherwise you will get a warning that the `search` variable wasn't used.

Answer (score 1):

```
if foo do
  bar
else
  baz
end
```

is equivalent to `if(foo, do: bar, else: baz)`. Once you know this, you can understand what the error message means: `params["search"]` should be piped into the `if`. This should fix the warning:

```
def index(conn, params) do
  studios =
    params["search"]
    |> if do
      Studio.search(Studio, params["search"])
    else
      Studio
    end
    |> Repo.all
    |> Repo.preload(:address)

  render conn, studios: studios
end
```